# Android, Espresso. How check is soft keyboard is under view?

Tags: android-espresso

I have screen with EditText and button (under EditText). The requirement is when show soft keyboard it's must be under button. Is it possible to write Espresso unit test (or anoter test) that check this?

Comment: did my answer help you solve your problem?

Comment: Not it not help. Because your test pass when the button is visible. But I need to test pass only when: button is visible AND bottom border of button is ABOVE the softkeyboard.

Comment: ok, you mean the test passes although the keyboard is slightly over the button? this is because android espresso has a 90% visibility rule (=tests pass if 90% of the view item are visible). you can overwrite this then the button has to have 100% visibility

Answer (score 1):

The android keyboard is part of the system and not your app, so espresso won't be enough here.

I created the following layout in my test activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.masta.testespressoapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TEST" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to just use espresso the dirty solution would be:

```
@Test
public void checkButtonVisibilty2() throws Exception {
    onView(withId(R.id.edittext)).perform(click());

    try {
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        throw new RuntimeException("Button was there! Test failed!");
    } catch (PerformException e) {
    }
}
```

This test would try to click on the button, which throws a PerformException since it would actually click on the Softkeyboard - which is not allowed. 
But i would not recommend this way, it is quite a misuse of the espresso framework.

A solution a bit better imho would be using android UI automator:

```
@Test
public void checkButtonVisibilty() throws Exception {
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.edittext), isDisplayed())).perform(click());

    UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    UiObject button = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.masta.testespressoapplication:id/button"));

    if (button.exists()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Button is visible! Test failed!");
    }
}
```

This uses android UI Automator to try fetch the button UI element and check if it exists in the current screen. (replace the package and id in the "resourceId" call with the ones for your case)

For android UI automator u need this additional gradle imports:

```
// Set this dependency to build and run UI Automator tests
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'
```

A general thought: this kind of tests seems very error prone since you do not have real control over the soft keyboard and how it looks like, so i would use that with caution.